# Atribuir um rótulo a emails do Gmail a partir de um dataset usando o {gmailr}

Tags: r, gmail

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gmailr)
```

Estou tentando atribuir um rótulo (ou "marcador" para usar o termo empregado pelo Gmail) a um conjunto de emails específico usando o pacote {gmailr}.

Isto se deve à necessidade de baixar emails/anexos específicos. O que eu consegui até o momento foi apenas criar o rótulo. Mas não consigo atribuí-lo a nenhum email via {gmailr}.

Meus procedimentos:

1. Com um app devidamente criado na Google Cloud Console, eu obtenho as credenciais para acessar meu Gmail. A partir daí, uso as funções `gm_auth_configure ()` e `gm_auth()` para autorizar a minha sessão de R à acessar o Gmail.
2. Com o rótulo criado manualmente, eu consigo o acesso aos IDs dos emails.
3. Supondo que eu tenha criado um rotulo chamado 'teste':

```
emails <- gm_messages(search = 'label:teste', user_id = 'me')
```

4. Obtenho então uma relação com "message_id" e "thread_id".
5. Com a função `gm_id()` eu consigo extrair os ids de cada email:

```
emails_id <- emails %>%
  gm_id()
```

6. A partir daí uso a função `map()` do {purrr} para extrair as informações que preciso de cada email:

```
emails_id %>%
   map(~{
   email_data <- gm_message(.x)
   email_from <- gm_from(email_data)
   email_attach <- gm_attachments(email_data)
})
```

Mas apenas alcancei meu objetivo porque, no começo, eu atribui MANUALMENTE o rótulo "teste" a cada um dos emails que me interessavam. O que eu gostaria de saber é como faço essa atribuição via {gmailr} usando um conjunto de nomes ou emails.

O máximo que consigo é criar o rótulo via `gm_create_label('teste')`, mas não consigo atribuílo a nenhum remetente.

Por exemplo, suponha uma dataset:

```
df <- tibble(nome = c('FULANO', 'BELTRANO', 'CICLANO'),
             email = c('fulano@gmail.com', 'beltrano@gmail.com', 'ciclano@gmail.com'))


nome     email             
  <chr>    <chr>             
1 FULANO   fulano@gmail.com  
2 BELTRANO beltrano@gmail.com
3 CICLANO  ciclano@gmail.com
```

Como atribuir o rótulo 'teste', a cada um dos nomes ou emails do dataset?

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Não sei se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, então vou quebrar a resposta em duas possibilidades.

**Possibilidade 1**: Você quer alterar mensagens que já existem que foram enviadas por endereços dentro de uma lista. Nesse caso, acho que o que você procura é a função `gm_modify_message` e o código abaixo ilustra esse caso:

```
gm_create_label('teste2')
# aqui vc recebera o id da label teste2

for(email in df$email){
    emails <- gm_messages(
                search = stringr::str_glue('from:{email}'),
                user_id = 'me')

    emails_id <- emails %>%
    gm_id()

     purrr::map(emails_id, ~gm_modify_message(.x, add_labels = "id da label teste2"))
}
```

**Possibilidade 2**: Você quer enviar e-mails para as pessoas da lista garantindo que uma certa label apareça. Nesse caso o caminho será enviar o e-mail com `gm_send_message` guardar o id e atribuir a label desejada com `gm_modify_message`, assim como no caso anterior.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).